# XML schema for weather information

Tags: xml, xsd, weather

Are there any accepted (or defacto) schemas for representation weather information (current or forecast) in XML? Particularly ones that are supported via an API.

Answer (score 0):

There is [DWML](http://www.weather.gov/xml/), it is a US government format, but I don't know how widely used.

Comment: Do you know of any web services (global, not just US) that output DWML?

Answer (score 0):

Check out weather.com's web services.  i wouldn't know if it's a standard, but it is popular: http://www.weather.com/services/xmloap.html

Comment: The Weather.com API terms seem draconian!